# Javascript split array results

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I'm more so just looking to understand why the following occurs (I figured out how to get what I need).

When I use the array.split function, I've been able to get 2 different results, and wish to know why. Here is an example, because I'll explain it poorly.

```
var x = 'R11, L12, U13, D14'.split('x ');
//Will create x = ['R11', 'L12', 'U13', 'D14']
//using var y = x.split('x ') will produce the same result
```

But I've also been able to get the following:

```
var x = 'R11, L12, U13, D14';
x.split(', ');
//Will create x = ['R', '1', '1', 'L', '1', '2', 'U', '1', '3', 'D', '1, '4']
```

Does someone have a good explanation as to what is going on there?

Comment: Your first snippet appears to be inaccurate.  The element returned from `'R11, L12, U13, D14'.split('x ');` is an array of a single string.  Not multiple strings.  I just popped it into my browser console to verify

Comment: Same with the second snippet.  I'm not sure how you are seeing the results you say you are seeing.  https://jsfiddle.net/2Lkyrbqd/

Comment: Apparently I keep messing up. I edited the code above, but it should be x.split(', ');

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rz39w1o4/  Using ', ' they both behave the same

Comment: @Taplar really? I'm running them in https://repl.it/languages/nodejs and they are definitely returning different results for me.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ImpossibleComposedStructs

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

> If separator is an empty string (""), str is converted to an array of each of its UTF-16 "characters"

```
"XYZ".split("")
// yields: (3) ["X", "Y", "Z"]
```

Answer (score 0):

split is not an Array function and it is a String function.
hence in your first code snippet, `x.split('x ')` does not work

in your second example, I presume that you want to split the string into Array and the delimiter is ",". You can do this

```js
const x = 'R11, L12, U13, D14';
const arr = x.split(", ");
```

result is

```
["R11", "L12", "U13", "D14"]
```

in cases where the space after comma is missing or have more spaces, you can do this.

```js
const x = 'R11,L12,   U13, D14';
const arr = x.split(",").map(_ => _.trim());
```